# Wifi Adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04 , dual boot Dell Inspiron 7572

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless

Why does it happen that sometimes in my Dell Inspiron 7572, in Ubuntu 18.04 the wifi disappears automatically. It starts showing wifi adapter not found. How to resolve this issue? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Only in Ubuntu?

Comment: Internal or external wi-fi adapter? Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Does this happen when your resume from suspend (sleep)?